# How to show errors in Symfony2 application white page

Tags: php, symfony

I am working in an web application and I got access to the files of the project. I am trying to run in local.

I've downloaded all the source code and the vendor libraries. Then I tried to run the project by the console.

It seems to work fine, but when I try to open the page in my browser it is just white.

I don't even know how to start looking for an error. How can we look for bugs or errors in this case?

Comment: Do you have a local webserver, and properly configured/set up for running Symfony? Are error enabled on your webserver?

Comment: Try to look at web server logs and app/logs folder in your application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: It's working normally in the webserver

Comment: "It's working normally..."  Are you attempting to just copy the files from the server and run it from your hard drive without setting up a local server like WAMP?

Comment: @MatheusOliveira if you are using linux or windows system please check your folder permission once.